# CAPL Code to send signal value from a button

Tags: capl, canoe

I am using CANoe 11.0 to send a signal value from a button.

I have a message from a CAN db with 6 signals, 8 bits for each signal. The message is cyclic but with a cycle time of 0ms, so, in order to send it, I figured out I need a button. But everything I tried so far doesn't work.

eg:

```
on message X
{
    if (getValue(ev_button) == 1)
    {
        X.signalname = (getValue(ev_signalvariable));
    }
}
```

or I tried working on the signal itself:

```
on signal Y
{
    if (getValue(ev_button) == 1)
    {
        putValue(ev_signalY,this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is due to the callback. Both `on message` and `on signal` callbacks happen when that `message` or `signal` is updated on the bus.

In your code, you expect to update a signal, if you pressed a button, but only if you detect that signal was updated in the first place. Do you see the loophole?

To fix this, you may create a system variable, associate that with the button (so that it is `0 = not pressed` and `1 = pressed`), then use the `on sysvar` callback:

```
on sysvar buttonPressed
{
    // prepare message
    // send message
}
```

I assume you already have something like `message yourMessage` somewhere, and that you know the name of the signal from the DBC and that the DBC is linked to your configuration. So you'll need to:

```
// prepare message
yourMessage.yourValue1 = <some value>
yourMessage.yourValue2 = <some other value>
// ...
// repeat for all relevant signals
```

and then

```
// send message
send(yourMessage)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and sorry for the late response. In the meantime i found the answer but i will try what you suggested also.
What i did was to add the "output" syntax to each part where i was writing the signals so this becomes something like
on enVar ev_signalY
{
MessageX.SignalY = (getValue(this))
output(messageX)
}

Comment: @Luca Which is perfectly fine and not much different from the solution I am proposing. The button updates the envvar and you output it, instead of using a sysvar. Please note that since version 11.0+ CANoe is starting to mark the envvars as to be removed in a future release and be replaced by sysvars only. Still, if you think this can be accepted as answer, please [do so](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), or post your method as answer instead